# combobox entered value translated

Tags: jsf, combobox, icefaces, transliteration

I need to implement transliteration, i.e. I want my combobox to work only on Cyrillic data. When the user enters non Cyrillic character I transform the character into corresponding Cyrillic and return it to the combobox, but my problem here is that the combobox doesn't search my options. When I hit backspace it searches just like it should. I am skipping some event or something I cannot figure out because I am new with JSF.

Here is my combobox:

```
<ace:comboBox id="somCounty" styleClass="toCyr"
              value="#{myBean.county}"
              valueChangeListener="#{myBean.countyChange}"
              filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:selectItems id="countiesSelected" value="#{myBean.listAllCounty}"/>
    <ace:ajax render="@this somMunicipality map" execute="@this" />
</ace:comboBox>
```

and here is my function for mapping characters:

```
$(".toCyr input:first-child").bind("keyup", function () {
        var elem = $(this);

        var text = $(this).val();
        var convertedText = toCyr(text);
        $(this).val(convertedText);

    });
```

Note `toCyr(char)` is a simple function that maps roman characters into cyrillic.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I made it, here is my function `translate()` which I use it to translate a certain character and then press right arrow with code. I use this little fix with the `right arrow` in order to open the dropdown list which wouldn't show up previously. It doesn't have to be right arrow, it could be `shift`, `ctrl` or other key that wouldn't make change to user's text.

```
function translate(){
//    this selector is specified for jsf generated code
var target = $(".cyrillic input:first-child");
target.each(function () {
    var i = $(this);
    i.keyup(function () {
        $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', {keyCode: 39, which: 39}));
    });
    i.on("input", function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var text = elem.val();
        var convertedText = toCyr(text);
        //  convertedText = convertedText.toUpperCase();
        elem.val(convertedText);
    });
});
```

}

and here is my event trigger when I click on the combobox container:

```
$(".west-panel").click(function () {
     translate();
});
```

here is tab functionality, in my case I have 2 comboboxes, so when the user hits tab instead of click I want to trigger my function again:

```
$(".west-panel").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 9 || event.which === 9){
        translate();
    } 
 });
```

I know it's not the best desirable solution, but when you are stuck with components like I am, you have to find a workaround. I test it and it works just fine